# How to fix an error when calling the GetRawInputDeviceInfA Windows API function in Go?

Tags: windows, go

The task is to use Go to query the Windows API and get the system names of input devices.

When calling the `GetRawInputDeviceInfA` function from the Go program, I get the error 'Invalid access to memory location'. Here is the terminal message:

> Error: Invalid access to memory location.Type: 1 Descriptor: 65599

Here is the full code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

// defining an imitation RAWINPUTDEVICELIST
type rawInputDeviceList struct {
    DeviceHandle uint64
    Type         uint32
}

const RIDI_DEVICENAME uint32 = 0x20000007

var (
    user32                    = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    getRawInputDeviceListProc = user32.NewProc("GetRawInputDeviceList")
    getRawInputDeviceInfoProc = user32.NewProc("GetRawInputDeviceInfoA")
)

func main() {
    dl := rawInputDeviceList{}
    size := uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(dl))

    var devCount uint32
    _ = getRawInputDeviceList(nil, &devCount, size)

    if devCount > 0 {
        devices := make([]rawInputDeviceList, size*devCount)

        for i := 0; i < int(devCount); i++ {
            devices[i] = rawInputDeviceList{}
        }

        err := getRawInputDeviceList(&devices[0], &devCount, size)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
        }
        uiCommand := RIDI_DEVICENAME
        var pData uint32
        for i := 0; i < int(devCount); i++ {
            err := getRawInputDeviceInfo(&devices[i].DeviceHandle, &uiCommand, &pData, 0)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
            }

            fmt.Printf("Type: %v Descriptor: %v \n", devices[i].Type, devices[i].DeviceHandle)

        }

    }
}

func getRawInputDeviceList(
    rawInputDeviceList *rawInputDeviceList,
    numDevices *uint32,
    size uint32,
) error {
    _, _, err := getRawInputDeviceListProc.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(rawInputDeviceList)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(numDevices)),
        uintptr(size))
    if err != syscall.Errno(0) {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

// Get device info
func getRawInputDeviceInfo(
    deviceHandle *uint64,
    uiCommand *uint32,
    pData *uint32,
    size uint32,
) error {
    _, _, err := getRawInputDeviceInfoProc.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(deviceHandle)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(uiCommand)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(pData)),
        uintptr(size))
    if err != syscall.Errno(0) {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

I expect that the handle refers to the address of a real device and do not understand what generates such a message. Can someone help me, please?

P.S.
I rewrote the function header and an error message appeared.

```
func getRawInputDeviceInfo(
    deviceHandle uintptr,
    uiCommand *uint32,
    pData uintptr,
    size uint32,
) error {
    _, _, err := getRawInputDeviceInfoProc.Call(
        deviceHandle,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(uiCommand)),
        pData,
        uintptr(size))
    if err != syscall.Errno(0) {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The function calling

```
err := getRawInputDeviceInfo(devices[i].DeviceHandle, &uiCommand, pData, size)
```

And now error message is

```
Error: The parameter is incorrect.Type: 1 Descriptor: 65596
Error: The parameter is incorrect.Type: 0 Descriptor: 65594
```

Comment: If I read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdeviceinfoa) correctly, the handle is a handle, not a pointer to it, and `uiCommand` is also not a pointer, it's a 32-bit integer. To me, it looks like you're "cargo-culting" those `uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(BlahBlah))` encantations (but I can be wrong, of couse).

Comment: @kostix You may be right, but user32.NewProc.Call requires pointers specifically. And then the question changes to another one: how do I get a pointer to a handle?

Comment: «user32.NewProc.Call requires pointers specifically»–this is not correct: it requires a set of `uintptr`s, it's not a pointer, it's "pointer-sized integer": to cite what `go doc builtin.uintptr`–«uintptr is an integer type that is large enough to hold the bit pattern of any pointer». The reasoning behind this is actually simple (if surprising): this is a "raw" interface able to call _any_ syscall, and on this level, there is no high-level data types–only CPU register-sized integers of some known count (up to 6, IIRC). The code of a particular syscall then _interprets_ the values passed to it.

Comment: Hm... but this is another matter! I was inattentive, I should try to rewrite the code with this correction, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your update code still contains several problems I've referred to in my comments in the question's thread.

Here's a modified working version:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

// defining an imitation RAWINPUTDEVICELIST
type rawInputDeviceList struct {
    DeviceHandle uintptr
    Type         uint32
}

const RIDI_DEVICENAME uint32 = 0x20000007

var (
    user32                     = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    getRawInputDeviceListProc  = user32.NewProc("GetRawInputDeviceList")
    getRawInputDeviceInfoWProc = user32.NewProc("GetRawInputDeviceInfoW")
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(0)

    size := uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(rawInputDeviceList{}))

    var devCount uint32
    if err := getRawInputDeviceList(nil, &devCount, size); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if devCount == 0 {
        log.Fatal("no devices")
    }

    devices := make([]rawInputDeviceList, devCount)
    if err := getRawInputDeviceList(&devices[0], &devCount, size); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    const RIDI_DEVICENAME uint32 = 0x20000007

    for di := range devices {
        var devName [256]uint16
        size := uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(devName))

        sizeOK, err := getRawInputDeviceInfo(
            devices[di].DeviceHandle,
            RIDI_DEVICENAME,
            unsafe.Pointer(&devName[0]),
            &size,
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if !sizeOK {
            log.Fatalf("insufficient size; want %d\n", size)
        }

        fmt.Println(syscall.UTF16ToString(devName[:size]))
    }
}

func getRawInputDeviceList(
    rawInputDeviceList *rawInputDeviceList,
    numDevices *uint32,
    size uint32,
) error {
    r1, _, err := getRawInputDeviceListProc.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(rawInputDeviceList)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(numDevices)),
        uintptr(size))
    if r1 == uintptr(^uint32(0)) {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func getRawInputDeviceInfo(
    deviceHandle uintptr,
    uiCommand uint32,
    pData unsafe.Pointer,
    size *uint32,
) (bool, error) {
    r1, _, err := getRawInputDeviceInfoWProc.Call(
        uintptr(deviceHandle),
        uintptr(uiCommand),
        uintptr(pData),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(size)))

    if err != syscall.Errno(0) {
        return true, err
    }

    return r1 > 0, nil
}
```

It prints (under Wine):

```
\\?\HID#VID_845E&PID_0001#0&0000&0&0#{378de44c-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}
\\?\HID#VID_845E&PID_0002#0&0000&0&0#{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}
```

Key points:

- `HANDLE`'s type changed to `uintptr` (as it's defined as `LPVOID` by Win32 API).
- Fixed types of `pData` and `size` of `getRawInputDeviceInfo`.
- Fixed calculation of the size of the slice to hold the info on multiple devices: the lengths of Go slices are counts of their elements, not counts of bytes they occupy in total.
- Made use of `GetRawInputDeviceInfoW` instead of `*A` version to ease conversion to Go-native strings: they are encoded in UTF-8, and `FooA` functions return strings encoded using the currently active code page; even though device IDs are supposed to be all-ASCII, it's simply easier to use "wide" call which returns UTF-16-encoded strings. It also saves Windows from performing of re-encoding these strings to return them to us.
- Fixed handling of return values of syscalls (see `go doc syscall.Proc.Call` for more info).

Note that I do not handle the case of `getRawInputDeviceInfo` producing a name which is longer that 255 characters.

In general, please consult the MSDN docs on actual calls and make sure your wrappers follow the type rules of those calls, and so does error handling (Win32 API is known for its inconsistent rules for return values).

---

A not very obvious note of caution: *never* use `uintptr`s to store pointers to Go memory until you very well understand what happens. The problem with them is that they do not count as live references to memory – because they are not pointers. It means an innocently-looking code like

```golang
func Foo(ptr *Whatever) {
  var u uintptr = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
  // (1)
  someWin32Proc.Call(u)
}
```

might legitimately crash at runtime because at the point "(1)" the GC might kick in and free the instance of `Whatever` pointed at by `ptr` if this variable was the last reference to it, and the syscall will receive the address of a freed memory – a classic "use after free" problem.

Hence, generally, you only convert Go pointers to `uintptr`s right on the spots where you're evaluating parameters for a call: Go has special rule which guarantees in such cases the source pointers are considered live.

Still, it's okay to use `uintptr`s to *store* `HANDLE`s because they reference non-Go memory.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a great job and a most useful review! I learned a lot of non-obvious things that I didn't even know about (for example, about the *W version)! I started to study the comparative data types of Go and Windows API and a lot of things became clear. But I would never have guessed that uintptr should be wrapped like this uintptr(deviceHandle). Thanks again very much!